# How to get access token for microsoft graph api for php curl

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, php-curl

How to get access token for microsoft graph api without login of outlook account.
I also have tenant id and secret key of azure account and also add the necessary permissions.

I tried with below link but they asking for username and password of outlook account.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/ReplaceYourTenantId/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ReplaceYourClientId&response_type=code

Comment: If you have client id then open the below link for code generator https://login.microsoftonline.com/ReplaceYourTenantId/oauth2/authorize?client_id=ReplaceYourClientId&response_type=code
And this will redirect on callback url and you will get the code in callback url. Click here for more details:
https://errorgram.com/article/how-to-get-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api

Comment: The _point_ of OAuth is that it involves user interaction.